# How do i take the last n elements from a vector in R?

Tags: r

suppose I have daily time series data under variable name "prices", but im only interested in the past 100 days. How would i extract the last 100 elements from this variable?

Something equivalent to python's prices[-100:] but for R?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a vector:

```
tail(prices, 100)
```